# Alternative to scikit learn labelBinarizer in R

Tags: python, r, date, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I'm doing machine learning for time series prediction and I need to transform dates to vectors of zeros and ones. 
If I decide that the relvant information of the date is the day of the week on which the observation was made, I'd like to have a time series of vectors of length 7, that contains only one "1" placed in the first slot if it's a Monday, second if it's a Tuesday etc...

I'd like, for example for an input (like "2015-12-22 22:48:00") to be transformed into

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

if the relevant information is that it's a tuesday. Or a

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

If it's that it's 10 p.m

The `labelBinarizer()` from `sklearn.preprocessing` does that nicely in python, and I've looked for the equivalent in R, but haven't found it. Do any of you guys happen to know what I'm looking for ?

Here is the labelBinarizer() : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html

Right now I'm doing this in python : where Hour is a time series of the the exact hours at which my observations were made;

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as pp
lbday = pp.LabelBinarizer()
lbday.fit(list(range(24)))
pp.LabelBinarizer(neg_label=0, pos_label=1)
Hour = lbday.transform(Hour)
```

Then i export a csv of the binarized dates that I read with R.

Thank you !

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck? Did you study [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/277660/1305688)?

Comment: I'm not stuck, i just want to find an r package that does the same thing as python's labelBinarizer(). I'm looking for an efficient way, to avoid endless unreadable code. Thx for the link. Unfortunately it's not what I'm thinking about.

Comment: Give some more reproducible R inputs/outputs for us. Why, for example, do you drop everything about that date but the fact its Tuesday? Do you really want an encoding for dates, or for any multi-level factor (days of week, months of year, hours of day)? Can you link to the docs for python's labelBinarizer?

Comment: Why do you refer to "binarized dates" when all your code does is binarize the **hours**?

Comment: Spacedman, I want to be able to choose tobinarize according to the hour of the day, or the minute of the day, or the minute of the week (by enumerating all 10080 minutes of the week and building an 10080 long vector of 0s and one 1), or whatever I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
binarizer <- function(levels){
    f = function(v){
        m = matrix(0, nrow=length(v), ncol=length(levels))
        vf = as.numeric(factor(v, levels=levels))
        m[cbind(1:length(v),vf)]=1
        colnames(m)=levels
        m
    }
    f
}
```

Example:

```
> ab = binarizer(letters[1:5]) # valid values a to e
> ab(c("a","e","a"))
     a b c d e
[1,] 1 0 0 0 0
[2,] 0 0 0 0 1
[3,] 1 0 0 0 0
```